# RedHat Enterprise Linux9.2 に redhat-lsb-coreをインストールしたい

Tags: rhel, tableau

Tableau-serverをRHEL9.2にインストールしようとした際に、以下のエラーを出力しました。

```
エラー:問題: 競合するリクエスト
- redhat-lsb-core が提供されません tableau-server-20231.23.0806.1229-20231-23.0806.1229.x86_64 に必要です
(インストール不可のパッケージをスキップするには、'--skip-broken' を追加してみてください または、'--nobest' を 追加して、最適候補のパッケージのみを使用しないでください)
```

よってredhat-lsb-4.1-56.el9.src.rpmをダウンロードし、rpm installを行いましたが、再度同じエラーを出力します。RHEL9.2にredhat-lsbを導入する方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Server のインストール要件を確認してください。現時点で RHEL 9.x は非対応のようです。

https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/ja-jp/ts_aws_virtual_machine_selection.htm

> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)
>
>   - Tableau Server 2021.4.0 以降: 7.3.x 以上、8.3 以上 (9.x を除く)
>   - Tableau Server 2021.3.x 以降: 7.3 以降 (8.x を除く)

redhat-lsb-core のインストールに関して回答することは可能ですが、Tableau Server が正常に動作する保証はありません。どうしても RHEL 9.x が必要なようであれば、製品サポートへ問い合わせを行う事を検討してください。

---

拡張子 `.src.rpm` のファイルは「ソースパッケージ (SRPM)」と呼ばれ、普段インストールしている `.rpm` = バイナリパッケージをビルドするための元となる特別なパッケージです。

名前が示す通り「ソースコード」なので、これらを直接インストールするのではなく、まず `rpmbuild` コマンドでバイナリパッケージを生成してからインストールする必要があります。

**参考:**
[ソース RPM からのバイナリー RPM の再ビルド | Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/packaging_and_distributing_software/rebuilding-a-binary-from-a-source-rpm_packaging-software)
[SRPMからプログラムをインストールするには](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/223instsrpm.html)

RHEL 9.x 向けの redhat-lsb-core パッケージは用意されていないようなので、`.src.rpm` が入手出来ているなら自分でビルドするか、もしくはサードパーティのリポジトリがビルド済みのバイナリパッケージを配布しているようです。

[redhat-lsb-core-4.1-59.1.gf.el9.x86_64.rpm](https://rhel.pkgs.org/9/ghettoforge-x86_64/redhat-lsb-core-4.1-59.1.gf.el9.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはりRHEL9.xでのredhat-lsb0-coreは面倒ですね。
大人しく、OSのバージョンダウンを行うことにします。